# javascript new Date(date) return wrong day

Tags: javascript, date, compare

i was trying to confront tree javascript Date objects with this sintax

```
 var from = new Date(1900,0,0);
 var to = new Date();
 var dataTicket = new Date(dataString);

     if (dataTicket > from && dataTicket < to) {
     alert("OK");
     }
```

but i can't get this working because the dataTicket continue to give me the wrong day!

when i check in the console i have this values in the if statement:

dataString = "Tue Sep 10 2013 22:44:07 GMT 0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)"

from = "Sun Dec 31 1899 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)"

to= "Tue Sep 10 2013 23:32:44 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)"

and here come the strange thing:

dataTicket = "Wed Sep 11 2013 00:44:07 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)"

i can get it working because dataTicket value is one day after it's assignation, any clue about this?

Comment: Months start from `0`, days start from `1`

Comment: then if i set month 10 i will get september instead of october, right? but here i'm gettin day 11 while setting 10 :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dateString` has a broken `zone` part. For the RFC2822, the `zone` should have a `+` or `-`, but yours doesn't and then it's interpreted as UTC (+0000); in fact the time is 00:44:27 instead of 22:44:27.

```
dataString = "Tue Sep 10 2013 22:44:07 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)"
```

This `dataString` will work as expected (note the `+` sign)

Comment: this is really strange, the dataString is created with new Data(), why i lose the + sign? :\ i'm going to check this

Comment: ok, i need to encode the date object when i sent it in a ajax post :)